# Unix grep duplicate vowels search

Tags: unix, grep

I am stuck on a homework question. The question asks to display the lines, with `grep` and I can't use `-w` option, that contain **no duplicate vowels**.

My teacher said to find the *grep* command that could display two or more 'a's in a line which would, I think, be `grep 'a.*a' file` and then find the grep command that would display two or more 'u's which, I think, would be `grep 'u.*u' file`, combine them and then I should be able to get it. But I don't know how I would combine the grep commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine different regular expressions with `|`:

```
grep 'a.*a|e.*e|i.*i|o.*o|u.*u' file
```

Comment: I love you. Thank you very much :)